# How to set cell accessory to checkmark dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to set cell accessory checkmark in table view of particular data which are store in database, so when data load in table view I have to show which data is checked its cell accessory will show checkmark other as unchecked.

I tried a lot but cell accessory can not show checkmark in table view. If I try to manually click on cell it will show blue cell accessory to checkmark.

```
[mobject addObjectsFromArray:MSG];                        
for (int i=0;i<mobject.count;i++)                           
{                            
    for (int j=0;j<MSG.count;j++)                       
    {                      
        if ([mobject[i] isEqualToString:MSG[j]])                   
        {         
            if([dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"R%d",indexPath.row]])                
            {                       
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;                               
                cell.selected = YES;             
            }                
            else           
            {            
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;              
            }               
        }              
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your table calls tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: dataSource method you can set cell accessoryType and change it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdenfitier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdenfitier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdenfitier];
    }
    if (someCondition) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir for your fast reply,sir but data are display perfectly but it can't bind checkmark.here [mobject addObjectsFromArray:MSG]; so mobject is my database where data will bind through.

Comment: You got me confused with this comment. I assume you have tableView which dataSource uses MSG array as data array. So once you need to update some cell you can iterate through your MSG array and use [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSInedxPath indexPathForRow:i in section:0]] to find desired cells. Then you just update checkmark.